# Fuzzy case for static class vs. singleton

Tags: java, static, singleton

I'm writing a class that will hold row data from a file.  Therefore it'll have state, but it's **immutable** state and there will only ever be one set of data.  My initial implementation was a static class, with the initializer block calling the method to read the file.  By doing this, I could be sure that the data was read when the class was loaded, and none of the accessor methods for the data would have to check for that case.

A reviewer has commented that the class should be a singleton.  While I understand his argument about the class having state, I'm thinking that the fact that it's an **immutable** state (once the file is read, of course) nullifies this argument.

I do have some other concerns, including handling an `IOException` (thrown when the reading of the file fails) in a static initialization block, but I'd be interested in opinions about the static vs singleton issue.

Comment: Lots of opinions about singletons here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/137975/10077

Comment: Thanks, Fred.  I had no idea that there was so much opposition to them.  Or, at least, so much misuse of them in so many people's opinions.

Comment: My hope was that the immutability (bolded) issue would either 1) be a red flag that someone could identify as a clear-cut signal in favor of the static implementation, or 2) draw comments as to its irrelevance and redirect focus on the true criteria - assuming they exist - for making this decision.  The fact that five viewers felt that "answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions" is a good indication that said criteria don't exist, so I suppose that's an answer, too.  Meh.  It was worth a shot.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I prefer classes like that being singletons.

First, like you mentioned, it's easier to handle `IOException`s from within **your** code instead of having to deal with them being thrown at seemingly random times and failing the classloader.

Second, I really prefer singletons as they are still **instances** - and as such they're easier to replace when you're testing.

The simple java version of this principle could look like this:

```
public class MyProductionClass {
    protected DataHolder getDataHolder() {
        return DataHolder.getInstance();
    }

    public int addOneToDataHolder() {
        return getDataHolder.getIntData() + 1;
    }
}
```

Now, assume I want to test the business logic of `addOneToDataHolder()`. All I have to do is mock away the `getDataHolder()` method:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MyProductionClassTest {
    @Mock
    private DataHolder dh;

    private MyProductionClass prod;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        MyProductionClass prod = spy(new MyProductionClass());
        doReturn(dh).when(prod).getDataHolder();
    }

    @Test
    public void testAddOneToDataHolder() {
        when(getDataHolder.getIntData()).thenReturn(1);
        assertEquals(2, prod.addOneToDataHolder());
    }
}
```

Of course, with any CDI framework, this wold look even cleaner.

Comment: Thank you.  I can certainly make the switch w/o too much difficulty, but I'm wondering if my class really meets the singleton standard of needing to be the only instance.  I certainly don't want to re-read the file (which having multiple instances would cause), but I keep coming back to the fact that this seems to be basically a bunch of constants for which I want to provide access via methods instead of directly.  Hence the "fuzzy" in the title.  I'm still torn, but will take the weekend to mull this over.